# Изображение в RecyclerView

Tags: android

Не могу разобраться, как записать изображение в адаптере RecyclerView в методе onBindViewHolder (изображения хранятся в папке drawable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Еще как вариант можно обратиться в адаптере к массиву с загруженными картинками:

```
private int[] images = {R.drawable.android_image_1,
        R.drawable.android_image_2,
        R.drawable.android_image_3,
};
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder baseHolder, final int position) {

    //set image in ImageView
    holder.ivIcon.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.yourDrawable));
}
```